# Inductive heating of nested cylinders

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

Say that I have two long cylinders of material as shown that are in a region of oscillating magnetic field where the field direction is aligned with the long axis of the cylinders.  I want to calculate the inductive heating of each cylinder (let's pretend for a moment that none of the parameters like resistivity are temperature independent).   I know how to calculate the skin depth and therefore the heating when only one is present, but don't know how to deal with two cylinders.  Does the inner cylinder "steal" some of the magnetic flux by reducing the flux from its own induced current?  If so, how much?  I would think there would be time lag between the flux and the induced current.  Any thoughts or references explaining how this can be attacked?  Thank you[image: InductiveHeating]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the skin depth is small $\delta \ll R_1 $, the magnetic field will be completely shielded by the induced currents and the inner cylinder will no longer be heated.

On the contrary, if the skin depth is large, $\delta \gg R_1 $, we can neglect the induced currents and keep only the external magnetic field.

But these two situations are not optimal for induction heating. In the general case, it is necessary to solve Maxwell's equations in the magneto-quasistatic approximation : you must resume solving the Bessel equation in each domain.

With Ampère's theorem, it is not difficult to show that the magnetic field $B_1$ is uniform between the cylinders.

For the central cylinder, the solution will be of the same form as that for a solid cylinder. (Bessel function of the first kind with a complex argument). But with $B_1$ instead of $B_0$

For the outer cylinder, it is a little more complicated because it is probably necessary to take into account two independent solutions: Bessel functions of the fist and second type with a complex argument.

These solutions in the two cylinders must be connected to find the constants and $B_1$.

Once obtained the magnetic field, the equation $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{H}= \sigma \vec{E}$ gives you access to the electric field then to the average power density $<\vec{j} . \vec{E}>$

A priori feasible but surely a little long to write.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Thank you for this, Vincent.  This is definitely helpful.  I will follow your suggestions and I think this will get me where I want to go.  Thank you!